# How to deploy an application which uses opencv on Heroku?

Tags: python, heroku, opencv

I have been trying to deploy my app on Heroku but I get following error:
2019-01-08T23:19:07.321214+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: libSM.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I have tried adding every buildpack, I had found on the Web with no result at all.
My Aptfile:

```
libsm6
libxrender1
libfontconfig1
libice6
```

I should be able to deploy the application but I cannot do that.
Can you help me please? :)
Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the apt buildpack is not working for you, you can containerize your application. The docker container would contain all the apt dependencies. Then you can deploy the docker container directly to Heroku.

For information on deploying docker images: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime